# How to use comparison in Mongodb filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, user-accounts, mongodb-atlas

**Context**: I am making a website in which users can create accounts. Then they have to verify their accounts by opening the verification email. I am using Node.js and Mongodb.

**What I'm Trying To Do**: If the user has not verified their account in the past 24 hours, then delete their account.

**Example account to delete**:

```
{
    created: 3294038434,
    notValid: "dslafjksdfkj"
}
```

**Example account not to delete**:

```
{
    created: 203498324,
    notValid: false
}
```

The `created` key stores a date as a `number`.
If `notValid` is `false`, then the account is verified. If `notValid` is a `string`, then the account is yet to be verified and the string represents the verification code.

Is there a way to user `deleteMany()` and have a filter something like this?

```
{
   Date.now() > created + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 && typeof(notValid) == "string"
}
```

I know that I can just read every single user and then do the logic but is there a way to just have mongodb do the logic / filter for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from *mongo shell*, lets take these three input documents:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "created" : 1574831443519, "notValid" : "dslafjksdfkj-abc" }
{ "_id" : 3, "created" : 1574817043519, "notValid" : true }
{ "_id" : 1, "created" : 1574817043519, "notValid" : "abc-111" }
```

Create a filter for the query to select documents with the criteria:

> Date.now() > created + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 && typeof(notValid) ==
>   "string"

```
var queryFilter = { $cond: {
                       if: { $and: [
                                     { $eq: [ { $type: "$notValid"}, "string" ] },
                                     { $gt: [ new Date(), { $toDate: { $add: [ "$created", 86400000 ] } } ] }
                                    ]
                            },
                        then: true,
                        else: false
                     }
};
```

The query `db.colln.find( { $expr: { $eq: [ queryFilter,  true ] } } )` returns the document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "created" : 1574817043519, "notValid" : "abc-111" }
```

Applying the query filter to delete the matching documents:

```
db.colln.deleteMany( { $expr: { $eq: [ queryFilter,  true ] } } );
```

Deletes the document with `_id : 1`.

Note the `created` field has date/time as milliseconds. At the time I tested, the date/time and corresponding millis: `ISODate("2019-11-28T03:20:03.835Z")` and `1574911160308`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please paste a link to the documentation on queries like this? (If there _is_ documentation)

Comment: The issue at hand was the date comparison, and the input date was in the form of milliseconds, a number. The date comparison is 

done on two values: The [new Date()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/index.html) returns current date as `Date` object. The [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) is an  aggregation operator, and this converts a value (a string or number) to a date; it takes an input parameter, and in this case a number `created+86400000`.